# Scrolling speeds up on calling a requestanimationframe multiple times

Tags: javascript, scroll, smoothing, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to create a slider with an image gallery and to make it scroll smooth using the requestAnimationFrame.
It works almost perfect except one thing. If you slide more then 2 times in any direction the scroll speeds up and it looks bad. I would like to have the same speed every time I slide to right or left.
Can anyone give me a hint of how to do that?

```
              var currentPos = -200;
              var incrementer = .05;
              var id;

              function scrollNext() {

                incrementer += 1;
                currentPos = Math.pow(1.05, incrementer);

                item.scrollLeft += currentPos;

                id = requestAnimationFrame(scrollNext);

                if (!curr_slide.nextElementSibling) {
                  if (item.scrollLeft >= curr_slide.offsetLeft) {
                    item.scrollTo(curr_slide.offsetLeft, 0);
                    cancelAnimationFrame(id);
                  }
                  if (item.scrollLeft < curr_slide.offsetLeft) {
                    item.scrollTo(curr_slide.offsetLeft, 0);
                    cancelAnimationFrame(id);
                  }
                } else {
                  if (item.scrollLeft >= curr_slide.nextElementSibling.offsetLeft) {
                    item.scrollTo(curr_slide.nextElementSibling.offsetLeft, 0);
                    cancelAnimationFrame(id);
                  }
                }
              }

              scrollNext();
              curr_slide.nextElementSibling.classList.add('activeSlide');
              curr_dot.nextElementSibling.classList.add('currentDot');
```

Comment: I'd recommend to have a look at element.scrollIntoView() method instead. It supports different options to suit your needs.

Comment: I tried this aswell but a major problem about scrollIntoView is that it's not working on Ios safari with scroll options